# Vector field with specific properties

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following:

Does there exist in $R^3\setminus\{0\}$:

1. a vector field F such that  $div F = 0$, but is not solenoid
   (doesn't exist B such that F = ∇ × B)?
2. vector field F which is not potential
   (doesn't exist function $f$ for which is $F = ∇f$), but for which holds $∇×F = 0$?

How to solve this? Can this be generalized on $R^n\setminus \{0\}?$

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.